# Equivalent Circuit of Induction Motor

Tags: power, circuit-analysis, motor, induction-motor, induction

To find the equivalent circuit of the rotor side of an induction motor, the resistance and the reactance changes to ensure that the current in the rotor remains the same, whilst removing the slip term *s* from the induced voltage in the rotor, as seen below.

However, in the model, although I is constant, the actual resistance and reactance are changing.

Would this not mean that power dissipated changes?

For example, when the resistance is just R, then the power dissipated in the core is \$I^2*R\$, but this changes to \$\frac {I^2*R}{s}\$ in the equivalent circuit. I understand that this change really simply reflects the inclusion of Mechanical Work done.

My main source of confusion is regarding the reactive power consumed. In the original circuit, where the reactance of the rotor is \$sX\$, the reactive power is \$I^2(sX)\$, however, in the frequency equivalent circuit model of the rotor, the reactive power would change and be \$I^2(X)\$. How is this accurate, especially as reactive power is intrinsically linked with frequency?

The following image was taken from the following link.

[https://circuitglobe.com/equivalent-circuit-of-an-induction-motor.html#:~:text=The%20Equivalent%20Circuit%20of%20an,stator%20circuit%20for%20the%20operation](https://circuitglobe.com/equivalent-circuit-of-an-induction-motor.html#:%7E:text=The%20Equivalent%20Circuit%20of%20an,stator%20circuit%20for%20the%20operation).
[image]

Comment: It is customery to site sources where you get images.  This allows authors credit and allows us to get contex for the question.  Edit your question showing the textbook source.